# Datagridview rows duplicating

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

Everytime when I add a new row to my datagridview I get duplicated rows from the rows that I added before the current one. I am using an external mysql database.

```
private void FillTable()
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection DBConn = new MySqlConnection(MysqlConnectionString);
            MySqlCommand Command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT Voornaam, Achternaam, Leeftijd, GBDag, GBMaand, GBJaar, Adres, Woonplaats, Postcode FROM Libra_Klanten ORDER BY Voornaam", DBConn);
            MySqlDataAdapter Adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(Command.CommandText, DBConn);
            MySqlCommandBuilder Builder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(Adapter);

            DBConn.Open();
            Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Adapter.Fill(CustomersTable);

            CustomersDataViewer.DataSource = CustomersTable;
            CustomersDataViewer.DataMember = CustomersTable.TableName;
            CustomersDataViewer.AutoResizeColumns();

            DBConn.Close();

            DBConn.Dispose();
            Command.Dispose();
            Adapter.Dispose();
            Builder.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(Ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

And this is the code for the insert statement:

```
private void ButtonInsertCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TextBoxVoornaam.TextLength > 0 && TextBoxAchternaam.TextLength > 0 && NumLeeftijd.Value > 0 && DateGeboorteDatum.Value != null && TextBoxAdres.TextLength > 0 && TextBoxWoonplaats.TextLength > 0 && TextBoxPostcode.TextLength > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlConnection DBConn = new MySqlConnection(MysqlConnectionString);
                MySqlCommand Command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Libra_Klanten (Voornaam, Achternaam, Leeftijd, GBDag, GBMaand, GBJaar, Adres, Woonplaats, Postcode) values ('" + TextBoxVoornaam.Text + "','" + TextBoxAchternaam.Text + "','" + NumLeeftijd.Value + "','" + DateGeboorteDatum.Value.Day + "','" + DateGeboorteDatum.Value.Month + "','" + DateGeboorteDatum.Value.Year + "','" + TextBoxAdres.Text + "','" + TextBoxWoonplaats.Text + "','" + TextBoxPostcode.Text + "')", DBConn);

                DBConn.Open();
                Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                DBConn.Close();

                DBConn.Dispose();
                Command.Dispose();
                FillTable();
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Vul alle velden in.");
        }
    }
```

Each time I insert a new customer to the database a duplicate shows up from the previous rows that I added. I already tried to use `.Clear()` on the datagridview but that didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried calling `CustomersTable.Clear();` at the beginning of your `FillTable` method? Clearing the datagridview won't remove the previous data, you need to clear its datasource.

Comment: Try declaring CustomersTable inside your FillTable() method .

Comment: Neither of those things worked. I tried to add this at the beginning but that didn't do anything:

Comment: if (CustomersDataViewer.DataSource != null)
            {
                CustomersDataViewer.DataSource = null;
            }

Comment: If you call `CustomersDataViewer.DataSource = Null` then make sure to call `CustomersDataView.Clear()` or `CustomersDataView.RowCount = 0` to remove all the rows.

Comment: Apologies Chawin your first answer was right after all. I just typed it wrong at first. Instead of typing customerstable I still typed customersdataviewer. I changed it up to customerstable now and it worked.

Comment: Fantastic, I've provided an answer below for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your datagridview is bound to a datasource you will need to clear the datasource itself.

Run `CustomersTable.Clear();` at the beginning of your `FillTable`method to ensure that your datasource has no data in it; the datagridview will reflect this.